# Inconsistent behaviour of my Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression which is matching correctly when parameters are in their reversed order but not when they are in the intended order:

```
^\s*Proc\s+[a-z_][0-9a-z_]+\s*\({1}\s*([0-9a-z_ ,.]+)\s* as (?:pin|bit|byte|word|dword|float|sbyte|sword|sdword|Long|slong|double|string\*[0-9]+,*)
```

matches this text just like I want to:

```
proc HMI_SendNumber(Value As Sword, Object As String*10)
```

But if I reverse the order of the parameters I am looking for...:

```
proc HMI_SendNumber(Object As String*10,Value As Sword)
```

...I only get a match on the first one, i.e. `Object`. It only occurs when `String*` is present, so I guess it has to do with the `*10` element of it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The fact is that your Group 1 pattern does not match `*`. If you change it to `[0-9a-z_* ,.]+`, it will match, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVRSno/1).

Comment: That is not what I want to extract.  I wanted 2 matches, in the above example I was looking for a match for Object and a match for Value.

Comment: Where are you using this?

Comment: What variety of regular expressions? You will need to tell *somewhere* that you *wanted 2 matches*.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't get "two matches", you only get **one** of:

```
Value As Sword, Object As String
```

See, how `*10` is missing? That's because `[0-9a-z_ ,.]+` does not allow `*` to match, too. Likewise your other text only has **one** match of:

```
Object As String
```

What do you really want? One match of all parameters? Multiple matches - one for each parameter? Because it's totally irrelevant to define all the  `as (1|2|3...)` because it already matches your initial class. Your whole regex can be reduced to:

```
^\s*Proc\s+[a-z_][0-9a-z_]+\s*\(\s*([0-9a-z_ ,.]+)\s*\)
```

if there would be no `String*10` as data type. It can be fixed by including `*` as in:

```
^\s*Proc\s+[a-z_][0-9a-z_]+\s*\(\s*([0-9a-z_ ,.*]+)\s*\)
```

Beware that this still is only one **match**, not multiple matches. The match itself may have your desired multiple **parameters**.

Also this has nothing to do with Delphi. It's slightly Visual Basic at best.

Comment: I am looking to obtain a comma separated list of all the parameters between the bracket in this expression:  proc HMI_SendNumber(Object As String*10, Value As Sword) with a string returned of Object,Value.  Perhaps I need to do it in 2 goes, extract the text between  the brackets and then a second regex to extract each parameter.

Comment: (funny enough `^\s*Proc\s+[a-z_][0-9a-z_]+` should match `proc HMI_SendNumber`)